# How to run commands in IntelliJ SBT Shell?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I wan to run some sbt commands inside a SBT Shell?
I've got Scala plugin installed.
I've clicked [image]

the "start SBT Shell" button, and the output was like: 
[image]

This `x` isn't normal sbt prompt. Also putting a command and clicking enter/clicking "Execute products" button doesn't work.

How to run commands in IntelliJ SBT Shell?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The 'X' means that the prompt is currently not ready to execute commands because the shell is initializing or running a command. It should turn into a `>` once it is ready to run a command.

Comment: Do you know when it might be ready?
Or what configurations should I use?
Sbt works well from terminal.

Comment: Usually it just takes a few seconds. Does it not work for any project you try?

Comment: It is not changing for any of my projects (2 of them are from coursera - apache spark), one based on playframework

I am using Community Edition on Linux. Maybe it is a bug.

Comment: It sounds like a bug. Does it also not work for a plain new project? Do you have a link to a project it doesn't work for?

Comment: The same with the fresh new project. There is a link to coursera [course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/scala-spark-big-data).
I see that some people were updating their solutions on github [example](https://github.com/amirziai/big-data-scala-spark). 

Maybe I should play around it's options, eg. `Launcher (sbt-launch.jar)`. Currently is set to Bundled. I am not sure what does it mean.

Comment: In that case the problem is not with the project itself. The bundled launcher should also work fine. Do you get any output at all in the shell after what is in the screenshot? What version of the Scala plugin are you using?

Comment: No, I am not getting anything else. I am always keeping everything up to date. Currently plugin version: 
2017.1.15,
about Idea: 
```IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3
Build #IC-171.4424.56, built on May 12, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b21 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.2.0-42-generic```

Comment: This warrants a deeper look. I've created an issue on our issue tracker for you: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11998

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144591/discussion-between-justin-kaeser-and-rumid).